# Delete NSUserDefaults to corresponding UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to reinitialize all the data associated with a given cell when this one is deleted.

This is my function deleting the cell (cryptosArray is the array creating the cells):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            cryptosArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let encodedData : Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: cryptosArray)
            userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "cryptosArray")
            userDefaults.synchronize()


        }
    }
```

And this is a function that saves the amount entered in the `textfield` present in the cell:

```
    func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell, cryptoPrice: String) {

        if walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text == "" {
            return
        }
        let str = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        let dNumber = formatter.number(from: str!)
        let nDouble = dNumber!
        let eNumber = Double(truncating: nDouble)

        walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = String(format:"%.8f", eNumber)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text, forKey: "\(cryptoPrice)Amount")
        walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text = ""

    }
```

As you can see I am saving `walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text` with `"\(cryptoPrice)Amount"` inside the UserDefaults file where `\(cryptoPrice)` is a parameter corresponding to the cell.

How can I delete the corresponding `"\(cryptoPrice)Amount"` key when I delete the cell? I can't figure out how to pass the parameter to `commit editingStyle:` ..

Comment: FYI - UserDefaults is not the place to store your app data. And the call to `synchronize` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution is: create an array of cryptoPrices. Each cell should have a value in there. For example, you can initialize an array with all zeros (if it works for you I don't know). Then if user enters the amount, you delete the zero from the array and `.insert` a new value there. So then when you do deletion you may easily find your key by `indexPath.row`.

Hope it helps! But note: this is a very straightforward solution.

I would do this: don't use UserDefaults for such things. It's not a DataBase. Better to use Realm or CoreData. I understand that it's harder but there are many tutorials that may help you with that. Good luck! Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems like an amazing solution! I will look into this and report back when it works! Also you're right, time to stop using UserDefaults to store data

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need any other help of this works ;)
Yes, let's be good developers haha:))

Comment: @martin don't forget to accept the answer too if it works. so people know that it's solved ;)

Comment: Hi Tung, so I need to create and update a `cryptoPrices` array when the cells are created, then update the value when the user enters a new one for the cell and finally delete the array element of the corresponding cell with indexPath.row when deleting the cell correct? Could you show me an example about what you'd do, I am struggling here? I can't find a solution to update the value at the correct indexPath when the user enters a value.. It would be awesome to see some code! :) Thx

Comment: Array done and setup for deletion, how can I access the correct indexPath for the value inside `cellAmountEntered `?